# Symfony2 + tinyMCE Bundle - JustBoil.me don't show

Tags: symfony, tinymce, justboil.me

I have Symfony2 project with TinyMCE Bundle installed. When I tried to install justboil.me image uploader (http://justboil.me/) the plugin doesn't show in TinyMCE, I don't get any errors, everything else is working. Here's my config

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
    tinymce_jquery: false # set to TRUE after fixing the issue with loading queue
    language: %locale%
    external_plugins:
            justboil:
                url: "asset[/js/tinymce-plugins/justboil/editor_plugin.js]"
    theme:
        simple: 
            plugins:
                - "justboil advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak"
                - "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
                - "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
                - "emoticons template paste textcolor"
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image justboil"
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | stfalcon | example"
            image_advtab: true
        advanced:
            plugins:
                - "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak"
                - "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
                - "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
                - "emoticons template paste textcolor"
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | stfalcon | example"
            image_advtab: true
        bbcode:
            toolbar1: "bold,italic,underline,undo,redo,link,unlink,removeformat,cleanup,code,preview"
```

What am I doing wrong? It's the first time I user TinyMCE Bundle and justboil.me.

Comment: I had a problem with language files, but this was only wrong path to en.js, I modified the plugin and put the right path into code. Just throwing it out here, but I don't think those two things are connected in any way.

Comment: how do you perform the upload process in symfony. I added TinyMCE to my proyect and also JustBoil.me plugin, but how do you upload the file?

Comment: how do you integrate it with symfony?

Comment: how do you process the image after the integration of the plugin to the tinymce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to copy your justboil.me plugin to tinymce `plugins` folder. 
**rename** `justboil` folder to `jbimages`

here is example how to include plugin and configure button in toolbar

`plugins : "preview,jbimages", 
toolbar: "jbimages | bold italic underline | fontsizeselect",`

hope this helps you